# jQuery Tabs and Google Maps, pin not at center

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am using jQuery Tabs to show different `<div>` contents in tabs. My tabs are:

Description | Amenities | Pricing | Images | Location Map

The problem happens when I switch to the Location Map tab, in which I am using Google Maps. The pin is not showing at the center of the map. But when I use the same Google Map script without jQuery Tabs, then it works fine. Is there a way to have the Tabs, but still have the pin at the center of the map?

Comment: Can you show some code examples or ideally upload your files somewhere so we can have a look?

Comment: Hi, I am new user, so I cant post a long code.. I am sharing the link, please follow it : http://www.21flats.com/property_detail/36/27/1/Gurgaon.html      and here u will find a tab named as 'Location Map'

Answer (score 0):

It is showing dead centre for me, which browser are you using?

Here is a screenshot of it working in Chrome 17 on Mac: http://d.pr/UNiS

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is showing there as well, but the problem is that you have a higher zoom level for your map. You can reduce the zoom level in your map to show the pin at center.

Comment: Hi Refhat, I tried it, Whole map got adjusted according to zoom-level, but pin is not moving even a single pixel from its palce and this problem is in mozilla firefox only.

Comment: Actually there is nothing wrong in maps, looks like your php file has some problem. see this url in ff and it works http://www.21flats.com/googlemap.php?project_id=36&city_name=Gurgaon

Comment: Ya Refhat, you are absolutely right, But I am using jquery UI tabs for showing 4 divs in tabs. And my tabs are Description Amenities Pricing Images **Location Map** and due to these jquery UI tabs its only showing problem in ff only.

Comment: Hi Refhat, I make some changes in tab UI CSS. Here I changed   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }  **to**  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { position: absolute; left: -10000px; },, It gives me some positive response, but when I check throughout all dynamic pages, somewhere Pin is in center but somewhere is not.. Even I have cleared all the browsing histories and cookies..

Comment: Hi, as I made above changes, it creates some other problems to the website, it was showing large blank spaces below the footer, so I have to remove it again. Is there any other alternative.

Comment: I will take a look at it over the weekend.